# ¿Como obtener todos los items de un QTableWidget en una lista?

Tags: python, lista, pyqt5

necesito obtener todos los items de una tabla "QTableWidget"(PyQt5) en una lista o tupla.
He probado con:

```
item = []
rows = self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount()
for column in range(0,9):
    for n in range(rows):
        item = self.ui.tableWidget.item(n, column)
        print(item)
        n+=1
```

pero el metodo item() retorna una **"class"**, algun otro metodo para obtener los items en listas? O.O

Comment: ¿Qué representa rows?

Comment: se me olvido agregarlo, es este: rows = self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es almacenar en item los valores:

```
item = []
rows = self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount()
for n in range(rows):
   fila=[]
   for column in range(9):
      fila.append(self.ui.tableWidget.item(n, column).text())
   item.append(fila)
print(item)
```

Comment: Me retorna esto : ['46']
['46', '45']
['46', '45', '44']
['46', '45', '44', '43']
['46', '45', '44', '43', '42']
['46', '45', '44', '43', '42', '41']

Comment: ¿Pusiste el print(item) fuera de los for?

Comment: ingresa los campos en un mal orden, deberia ser [['46','valor1','valor2'], ['45','valor1','valor2'] ] y asi sucesivamente, que me retorne cada item como un array dentro de un array

Comment: si, coloque el print(item) fuera de los for y me aparece el mismo orden pero no repetitivo

Comment: Lo cambié, ahora debe devolverte una matriz con todos los datos que hay en la tabla

Comment: Excelente me sirvio, muchisimas gracias de verdad :)